# ¿Como puedo comparar si un valor existe dentro de un grupo de valores en mysql?

Tags: mysql

Quisiera saber por medio de un select si puedo buscar por mediante un grupo de datos un valor en especificio

ejemplo:

```
const array = ['1', '2', '3'];
```

de este arreglo me gustaría saber si existe un valor 1 y en caso de que existe me retorna un boolean

```
/* un ejemplo con javascript sería: */ array.includes('1'); // retornar verdadero porque si hay un elemento 1
```

he probado intentado hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
Select (1, 2, 3) = 1
```

El problema está que en que me arroja el ERROR: 1241, he probado intercambiando los parentesís por corchetes pero esta sintaxis no es posible en mysql.

Si utilizo el select si parentesís toma cada numero como una columna diferente y solo termina comparando con el ultimo elemento colocado

Comment: Puedes ocupar la cláusula [`expr IN (value, ...)`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php), que en tu caso sería algo como `SELECT valor_a_buscar IN (1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: @ricardo-dlc Gracias, me funcionó correctamente